# TypeScript: Specify a directory to look for module type definitions

Tags: typescript, import, module, type-definition

Heyho,

I want to use some javascript libraries in my typescript code for which there are no typings in npm. So I wrote the typings myself and put them in a `definitions` directory in my source tree. However, I could not get typescript to look in that directory for those modules.

My directory structure looks like this:

```
+-node_modules
| |
| +-moduleA
| |
| +-moduleB
|
+-src
| |
| +-definitions
| | |
| | +-moduleA.d.ts
| | |
| | +-moduleB.d.ts
| |
| +-ts
|   |
|   + ... all typescript code ...
|
+-tsconfig.json
```

I tried including the modules in the `definitions`-directory using

- `include`
- `files`
- `typeRoots`
- `paths`

However none of it worked.

Can somebody tell me, how to get typescript to include those typings?

PS: Why is the TypeScript module handling so complicated???

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types",
      "./some-custom-lib"
    ]
  }
}
```

the typeRoots string array is just for that. In addition to your regular "node_modules/@type", add a custom made typings folder.

Comment: This seems to work as long as I do not have any import-statements in my module definition. But without the import I cannot type my module correctly.

Comment: This doesn't work because `typeRoots` expect typings in script format instead of module format.

Comment: Is that documented somewhere? I could not find information on such things.

Comment: I have no idea, this is just what I do.

Comment: I found my typeRoots were ignored as I had the files ending with .d.ts ; changing to .ts instead works; so this approach no doubt requires some other compiler options set to not ignore the .d.ts (at least in my case)

Comment: @jsf Move your import statement inside your module declaration, e.g. `declare module 'my-module' { \n import type { Buffer } from 'node:buffer' ...`. This solved the import statement issue that I also had.

Answer (score 8):

You can include them with the [triple-slash Directives](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html) to  direct the compiler to use them.

E.g. create an `index.d.ts` file and put it your definitions folder. There you can include every custom typing you made. It could look like this

```
/// <reference path="react.patch.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="custom-typings.d.ts" />
```

Inside the typings file the first line has to be

```
/// <reference types="nameOfIt" />
```

Then in your `tsconfig.json` you include them in the `files` field e.g.

```
"files": [
    "definitions/index.d.ts"
  ]
```